# Dictionary key related issue

Tags: python

This one issue has been bothering me and I have no clue how to resolve this. I am using Jupyter notebook to run this and am using python 3. I defined the dictionary as below and need to retrieve **100**

```
 d = {'k1':123,'k2':[0,1,2],'k3':{'insidekey',100}}
```

When I print this out  it prints out as

```
{'k1': 123, 'k2': [0, 1, 2], 'k3': {100, 'insidekey'}}
```

Similarly when I print out as d['k3'] 
it prints out the item as `{100, 'insidekey'}` instead of `{'insidekey', 100}`.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

When I try to run it anyway as d['k3']['insidekey'], I get the following error message

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 d['k3']['insidekey']

TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Appreciate the help in advance

Comment: Note that dictionary is in the form of {key: val}. If you look at `{100, 'insidekey'}, it does not follow that format.

Comment: You need a colon instead of a comma between insidekey and 100

Comment: `{100, 'insidekey'}` is a set. The order of elements in a set isn't guaranteed. Maybe you want a dictionary `{'insidekey': 100}`

Comment: @RBowen   Thanks for catching that.. I was folowing along in a tutorial and didn't catch that. Appreciate the quick help

Comment: @Sri  Thanks to you as well.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks a ton

Comment: First time user here so not sure how to mark this as answered

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> {100, 'insidekey'} == {'insidekey', 100}
True
```

These two expressions are equivalent because sets (created by specifying comma-separated elements inside `{}`) aren't ordered.  If you want an ordered collection, use a list:

```
>>> [100, 'insidekey'] == ['insidekey', 100]
False
```

If you want a key: value association, use a dict:

```
>>> {100: 'insidekey'} == {'insidekey': 100}
False
```

Note that with dicts, while it's significant which key goes with which value, the keys themselves are not ordered:

```
>>> {'insidekey': 100, 'outsidekey': 200} == {'outsidekey': 200, 'insidekey': 100}
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it seems like you are defining your nested dictionary incorrectly:

```
    'k3':{'insidekey',100}
```

should have a semicolon instead of a comma:

```
    'k3':{'insidekey':100}
```

Now, if I run

```
    print d['k3']['insidekey']
```

I get the output `100`

Answer (score 0):

The value associated with 'k3' is a set. Sets are unordered, thus no order is guaranteed. And regarding your second question, sets, unlike lists are not indexed. You cannot access set elements like the way you are trying. You need to declare `d['k3'] = {'insidekey' : 100}` in order to have `d['k3']['insidekey']` working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a dictionary as an element inside a dictionary you need to follow the same syntax as the one you used to define the outer one. You seem to have correctly defined the outer dict but you might have mistyped a comma for a colon in your inner dict.

So if you would just correct your code in this fashion you will get the result you're looking for. Here's how

```
{'k1': 123, 'k2': [0, 1, 2], 'k3': {'insidekey': 100}}
```

This way you can access your data (which is 100) with this code

```
d['k3']['insidekey']
```

Answer (score 0):

A set in Python is not subscriptable. In your case d is a dictionary that has for they key k3 a set value ({'insidekey',100} is a set !!).  So d['k3'] is a set. Since sets are not subscriptable, when you do 
d['k3']['insidekey'] you get the error you mentioned ( TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable ).